# React Native: Text and Growing TextInput in a responsive ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scrollview, textinput

Using RN 0.45, for iOS and Android:

I'm trying to create a view that is like the "reply" view of the reddit app, that I think would be as follows:

- A header (Text) that is static
- Below the header, an input (TextInput) that grows/shrinks to the size of the content
- Encapsulating both, a scrolling view (ScrollView) with a static height that is above above the top of the keyboard

[image: example picture]

When putting this view together, I'm having trouble

The simple version of my code looks more or less like this, though this doesn't accomplish what I want because the TextInput scrolls inside the scrollview rather than with the scrollview:

```
<ScrollView style={{height: 200}}>
  <Text>Header Text</Text>
  <TextInput
    multiline
    underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
    autoCapitalize='none'
    autoFocus
    editable
  />
</ScrollView>
```

I'm looking for a way to

1. Dynamically size the TextInput within the scrollview
2. When the cursor is within the TextInput at the bottom of the visible part of the scrollview and the user types something that makes a new line, the scrollview will shift to show the new text line
3. When the cursor is in the middle of the TextInput and creates a new line, the scrollview does not move

I'm wondering if there are examples of this kind of view in another app, or a method that people have used to create this kind of view, especially if it is different than the method I'm trying out or uses a library made for this kind of thing!

EDIT: Another attempt using [AutoGrowingTextInput](https://github.com/wix/react-native-autogrow-textinput), but the overall UX doesn't quite work as expected as creating a line in the middle of the of the textinput area causes the ScrollView to scroll all the way to the end --

```
    <ScrollView
      style={{ height: 240 }}
      ref={(scrollView) => { this.scrollView = scrollView; }}
      contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
      onContentSizeChange={() => {
        this.scrollView.scrollToEnd();
      }}
    >
      <Text>Header Text</Text>
      <AutoGrowingTextInput
        multiline
        underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
        autoCapitalize='none'
        autoFocus
        editable
      />
    </ScrollView>
```